# Star Trek: Deck Building - Upgrade Rules

Tags: star-trek-deck-building-game

When a card is suppose to be upgraded do you remove the card being upgraded from your deck?  Then the card gained from the upgrade, are you allowed to play that card?  If you upgraded a card already on the bridge, can you play the gained card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you remove an upgraded card from your deck. **No**, you are not allowed to play a card immediately when you gain it. Normally, when gain a card it goes to your discard unless the card specifically tells you otherwise. **No**, if you upgrade a card from your bridge, the gained cards normally go to your discard area, unless the card says specifically otherwise.

From the [Rulebook2.0 on Bandai](http://www.bandai.com/startrek/Rulebook2.pdf)'s website, (page 24-25 Glossary):

> **Gain** - Move a card from Starbase to your discard area (Some effects may move it to another area).
>
> **Upgrade** - This is short for “Trash the designated card and gain a card from Starbase costing up to the designated amount more than the trashed card”. So you can trash a card of cost X and gain a card with a cost less then X.
>
> **Trash** - Move a card to one of the following areas depending on where the card originated from:
>
> - If it is a starter card, remove it from the game.
> - If it is a Basic Character card, move it to its pile on Starbase.
> - If it is a card that started in the Starbase Deck, move it to the Starbase Discard Area.
> - If it is a Borg Card, move it to the Borg Card Pile

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen that glossary.  Just the star fleet academy I wasn't sure since it said 'Upgrade a card on the bridge or in your hand' i assumed the card simple changed placed with the new card.

Comment: "Upgrade a card on the bridge or in your hand," would fall under the general answer that is given in the glossary. When you upgraded the card from your bridge, you would trash it, and then gain a card (into your discard) from the Starbase